# solr / lucene query highlighting in arabic

Tags: solr, lucene, arabic

I'm working with Solr 4.1 and I want to highlight an arabic query. but it doesn't  work correctly. It finds the word to be highlighted correctly but when it want to add the highlight  tag (for example ) it cant find the write index to add these tag to. for example it create something like this for query pizza.

```
<str>i eat<em> pizz</em>a every weekend</str>
```

it works for English correctly but i just want to explain what i mean.

or here  is an arabic example for query علی:

```
<str>أَخْبَرَنِي الرَّئِیسُ الْعَفِیفُ أَبُو الْبَقَاءِ  هِبَةُ اللَّه‌ِ بْنُ نَمَا بْن<em>ِ عَلِي</em>ِّ بْ</str>
```

which i expect to be:

```
<str>أَخْبَرَنِي الرَّئِیسُ الْعَفِیفُ أَبُو الْبَقَاءِ  هِبَةُ اللَّه‌ِ بْنُ نَمَا بْنِ <em>عَلِيِّ</em> بْ</str>
```

note that I use the following field description:

```
<fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer> 
    <charFilter class="searchEng.solr.ar.CharFilter" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- for any non-arabic -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ar.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <!-- normalizes ﻯ to ﻱ, etc -->
    <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

the first charFilter just normalize some Arabic characters.

Comment: What kind of analyzers are you using on the field?